# $\pi_1(F_4)$ contains $\pi_1(F_{10})$ as a subgroup of index $3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups

Let $n$ be a natural number. We denote by $F_n$ an orientable, compact & connected surface of genus $n$.

I now have to show that $\pi_1(F_4)$ contains $\pi_1(F_{10})$ as a subgroup of index $3$. However, I am not supposed to calculate the fundamental groups explicitly, but I should construct a properly discontinuous group action on $F_{10}$. But I have trouble finding such a suitable action.

Can someone give the group action or refer me to a work where this is shown? Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest drawing a picture of $F_{10}$ and $F_{4}$ and see how $F_{4}$ might show up.

Comment: FWIW, the title question (probably not what was meant) and the body question do not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use the following to represent $F_{10}$, then it is clear that it admits a $3$-fold rotational symmetry, so $\Bbb Z_3$ acts on $F_{10}$ properly discontinuously, where the action is generated by rotation of angle $2\pi/3$. The quotient space $F_{10}/\Bbb Z_3$ is homeomorphic to $F_4$, and $q:F_{10}\to F_{10}/\Bbb Z_3$ is a $3$-fold covering. It follows from covering space theory that $\pi_1(F_{10})$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(F_4)$ of index $3$.

[image]

In fact the following statement holds:

> There exists an $n$-sheeted covering $F_k\to F_l$ if and only if $k=n(l-1)+1$. [Your problem is the case $k=10$, $l=4$.]

$\Rightarrow:$ If $p:F_k\to F_l$ is an $n$-sheeted covering, then $2-2k=\chi(F_k)=n\chi(F_l)=n(2-2l)$. Rearranging, we get $k=n(l-1)+1$.

$\Leftarrow:$ We can again use the "windmill" and exploit the $n$-fold rotational symmetry of $F_k$.

Comment: Wow, what a nice answer! Your drawings also really helped me to visualize the problem, thanks!